# Unable to get project to run now that it's 64 bit

Tags: c#, build, 64-bit

I wrote a project in C# that I need to run in 64 bit.

The project is part of a solution with other projects, and it references some of them, which are libraries.

I get the error `"Could not load file or assembly 'KittenLibrary' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format."`

I have gone into configuration manager, and set

Active solution configuration: Debug

Active solution platform: x64

KittenProject: Debug, x64, Build
KittenLibrary: Debug, x64, Build

and on the Properties for both projects, I have changed it to

Configuration: Active (Debug)
Platform: x64
Platform target: x64

I've deleted all bin / obj folders, cleaned the solution, but I still get the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

This is being hosted on my local IIS.

Edit: I have tried removing references to my other projects, so I am only referencing the core dlls and entity framework, it won't run my kittenproject in 64bit.

Comment: probably one of the DLL's the KittenLibrary is using was compiled usin x86 which means you can't load it in a x64 project

Comment: What we do is to set ALL libraries to compile for AnyCPU, and then only set the required bitness for executables (apps or services). (This doesn't work for libraries that are using unmanaged DLLs with a certain bitness though.)

Comment: So if I make my project 64 bit, I can't reference any other projects unless they are 64 bit AND all their libraries like stuff from nuget etc. is 64 bit?

Comment: If you make a project 64 bits, you can reference any projects that are either AnyCPU or 64 bits. That's why we make all class libraries AnyCPU. It's then up to the executable project (and ONLY the executable project) which bitness to use.

Comment: I've reset everything back to normal, and the project runs. Now I go into configuration manager and change my KittenProject to x64, and it says it can't run KittenProject with the above error. But I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WCF projects apparently don't work when switches to x64 with no explanation or fix that I have been able to find. There is more information here: [WCF 64 bit not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837746/wcf-64-bit-not-working)

I am going to have to write my project using something else, maybe mvc 4 web api

Comment: Perhaps you have to go to the AppPool advanced settings and turn OFF "Enable 32-Bit Applications"?

Comment: Tried that, the issue is that it references non-64bit libraries. It might be possible to manually reference 64 bit versions (if they exist) but I wouldn't like to try.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this problem myself on more than one occasional. For me the fix is setting the platform target to x86 instead of AnyCPU or x64. You may want to give that a try.

Comment: Tried this but no luck.