# Error when running exchange commands from WCF services

Tags: wpf, vb.net, powershell

So I made this application that runs exchange commands and sends results to SQL server, in a way server maintenance. I ran the the function that runs exchange commands locally as a class, in order to deploy over multiple machines the application should connect to WCF service that calls functions in a class. I tried moving my local functions into the WCF service files as well as moving the class to a larger class the WCF service files reference. Now I'm getting an error that the exchange commands aren't being recognized despite it working when run locally. Do runspace and powershell command execution not work over WCF services or did I set my projects up wrong.

I'm deploying my app to 64bit machine. The class the WCF service references is also being built on 64 bit machine.

```
Public Sub GetExchangedata(strComp As String, strServ As String)
  Dim strMailboxes() As String = {"DiscoveryMailbox", "EquipmentMailbox", "GroupMailbox", "LinkedMailbox", "LegacyMailbox", "RoomMailbox", "SharedMailbox", "SchedulingMailbox", "TeamMailbox", "UserMailbox"}
  Dim MyStringBuiler As New StringBuilder()
  Dim rsConfig As RunspaceConfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create()
rsConfig.AddPSSnapIn("Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010", New PSSnapInException)
  For Each strMailboxtype As String In strMailboxes
    Using myRunSpace As Runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(rsConfig)
      myRunSpace.Open()
      Dim mypipeline As Pipeline = myRunSpace.CreatePipeline()
      Dim rsInvoker As RunspaceInvoke = New RunspaceInvoke(myRunSpace)
      rsInvoker.Invoke("Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass")
      Dim exchCommand As String = "Add-PSSnapin 
      Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010;(get-mailbox - 
      recipienttypedetails " & strMailboxtype & " ).count "
      Dim strProc As String = "(get-process).count" 'this command works 
      mypipeline.Commands.AddScript(exchCommand)
      'mypipeline.Commands.AddScript(strProc)
      mypipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String")
      Dim outputs As Collection(Of PSObject) = mypipeline.Invoke()
      For Each result As PSObject In outputs
        MyStringBuiler.AppendLine(strMailboxtype & " : " & result.ToString())
        dsExchangeAcounts.Tables(0).Rows.Add(strComp, strServ, strMailboxtype, result.ToString)
      Next
      rsInvoker.Invoke("Set-ExecutionPolicy Default")
      myRunSpace.Close()
    End Using
  Next
End Sub
```

This code runs perfectly on my local machine but errors when running from WCF services client.

Comment: Sounds like a permissions / identity issue. Who is the WCF code executing as on the server?

Comment: @RQDQ sorry I'm very new to WCFservices, I'm not sure how to check what youre asking. I have a local WCf service for testing that I'm using right now. I have Visual Studio running under Admin deplaying to a 64bit machine.

Comment: No worries. Am I correct in assuming that you're deploying / running on IIS server? You can check the identity of the AppPool that is running your WCF site in IIS Manager. It's probably one of the built in users, and that user probably doesn't have access to the network.

Comment: looking at IIS under Application pools there a bunch of MSExchange and the DefaultAppPool, would that be the one running my WCF service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the error turned out to be my WCF service application was not running in 64 bit mode, and powershell doesn't like that 32 bit mode. Followed this link : [WCF 64 bit not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837746/wcf-64-bit-not-working)

After configuring it to run in 64 bit only , my code executed perfectly. Awesome